# how to save data after download image?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-5

I am facing one problem i want to save data after downloading an image. My image has been successfully downloaded after that i want to maintain the history of downloads.Here is my Function:-

```
enter code here
public function UserImageDownlaod($userid=null,$imageid=null){
    $imagedata = DB::table('alt_images')->where('id',$imageid)->first();
    $imagedata = json_decode(json_encode($imagedata),true);
    $destination = 'images/ContributorImages'.'/';
    $pathToFile = $destination.$imagedata['img'];
    return response()->download($pathToFile);  
    //Now i want to save the history of downloaded images
    $history= new DownloadHistory;
    $history->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $history->alt_image_id = $imageid;
    $history->save();
 }
```

Now you can see after this **return response()->download($pathToFile)** line i want to save the history data. I want when User click on OK button then data will saved on history table. Can anyone help me.
[image]

Comment: This is the default browser popup. We are not able to got its event in code.

Comment: if i save before the response download it will saved but if user clicks on cancel buttton.then data will be saved it create problem for us

Comment: can't you put return statment at the end of the function

Comment: if i put in end i know my data will be saved but if user click on cancel then it will also save data in history table

Comment: Why don't you do something like -  When the user clicks on any download button generate a popup by javascript with a message like "Are you sure want to download the image". Then you'll get both OK & CANCEL button in the popup. Then, if the user clicks on "OK" then take it as your user want to download the image else don't execute the Download image code.

Comment: is there any link of live example you have ?

Comment: At the very moment I don't have nay sample code but, if you tell what exactly you can't able to understand then maybe I can help you on that. Basically, what I want to say just before browser's download manager prompt user to download image or not your application should ask user by using javascript that "Do they really want to download the image"? Then according to the response of user decide what to do.

Comment: @kunal : Check Philipp's reply. That's what I'm telling to do you.

Comment: I understand your point if open the modal of cancela nd download if user click on cancel i will hide  the modal if user click on download button again default browser modal will open so this is issue

Answer (score 0):

The popup you showed us is from the browser. At the point, you see this popup, the browser might already started to download the file in the background. As this is part of your browser and you dont have any callback about pressing ok/cancel, there is no direct way to determine, what the user did.

A simple workaround would be, to show the user an alert box in javascript and ask, if he really wants to download the file.

```
<a href="{{ action(...) }}" onclick="confirm('are you sure?')">Download</a>
```